# How to name custom search page PHP file?

Tags: templates, search

I'm reading about how to create a [custom search page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page). It's not clear for me how to proceed, in the wordpress documentation I've read that I can't use the name `search.php` for a search page because it's a reserved template name of wordpress. Can someone explain to me what's the best way on how to name my custom search page?

Comment: Did you continue to read the guide at your link? It explains what to do.

Comment: You want a custom search form or a custom search result page?

Comment: @SabbirHasan I want to create a custom search result page.

Comment: Then you can proceed with `search.php` template.